# What's the correct one: "one did show up" or "one showed up"?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, differences, past-tense, do-support

Is there any difference between these two sentences? Is one of them wrong?

1. Even if a ship did show up
2. Even if a ship showed up

Comment: For most purposes, there's no difference. But note that ***did*** provides emphasis for the verb ***show up***, so you couldn't include that if you actually wanted to emphasise that what might show up could be a ship rather than, say, a submarine. To convey that emphasis, you'd need to stress ***ship***, which you can't reasonably do at the same time as stressing ***did***.

Answer (score 0):

The first would work in a sentence in this context: I don't think ships dock here now. Even if a ship did show up at this pier, it would probably not take passengers on board.

The second would work in the following context: There are so many of us, we won't fit in that sailboat. Even if a ship showed up, we would hardly fi